# Creating batch file to open IE Settings

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer

I'm looking to create a simple batch file to automate some user operations in Windows.

Specifically, to open `Internet Options > LAN Settings > Advanced` and then OK and/or EXIT out of all three Windows.

I don't need to change any settings -- just simply go into the Windows and back out.

I'm new very at creating batch files and am looking for some information on how best to approach this, as well as a possible solution.  :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try with the  CLSID Keys : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**sendkyes.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) :

```
start "" explorer.exe shell:::{A3DD4F92-658A-410F-84FD-6FBBBEF2FFFE}
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
call sendkeys "Internet Properties" "+{tab}{right}{right}{right}{right}{right}{right}"
timeout 3
call sendkeys "Internet Properties" "{enter}"
```

Comment: I did think sending keystrokes may be an option but I came across alot of stuff saying to use it as only a last resort. I'm glad you responded with this it gives me a bit more confidence to try keystrokes, thanks :)